# How does EF DB First works for subsequent updates into DB?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

Generating POCO from db  works like a charm, however what if further tables / columns are added into DB.

How to perform incremental updates of POCO in case of EF DB first?

Here are two alternatives I could think of:

1. Or shall we fall back to code-first style from there onwards?
2. or just keep adding incremental columns / tables manually into
   respectively into POCO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated classes are partial, so you can just overwrite them with any schema changes in the database.